# Common Style for PasswordBox and TextBox

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I define a common Style for the TextBox and the PasswordBox?

My approach, I have define a Style for the TargetType FrameworkElement but this doesnt work as common style, then few propertys doesnt exist on the FrameworkElement.

My TextBox Style is equals the PasswordBoxStyle

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border Name="Border" CornerRadius="4" Padding="2" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" >
                    <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<Style x:Key="textboxPasswordboxStyles">
  <Setter Property="Control.ControlProperty" Value="value" />
  <Setter Property="TextBox.TextboxSpecproperty" Value="value" />
  <Setter Property="PasswordBox.PasswordBoxSpecProperty" Value="value" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource textboxPasswordboxStyles}">
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource textboxPasswordboxStyles}">
</Style>
```

Comment: Style Property "PasswordBoxSpecProperty" doesnt found in  "System.Windows.Controls.PasswordBox"

same for "ControlProperty" "System.Windows.Controls.Control" and 
"TextboxSpecproperty" "System.Windows.Controls.TextBox"

Comment: ah lol, okay I understand.. i have solved ... TextBox.MinHeight thx : )

Comment: @MarioBinder how did you solve the error concerning the properties? I have the same problem. Shouldn't I put the style property in the App.xaml ? In a resource directory .....

Answer (score 3):

```
<Style x:Key="textboxPasswordboxStyles" TargetType="Control">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="22"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1.5"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>

            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Name="Border"  CornerRadius="8" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" >
                        <Border.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" x:Name="Background" />
                        </Border.Background>

                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray" x:Name="BorderBrush" Opacity="1"/>
                        </Border.BorderBrush>

                        <ScrollViewer Margin="10,0,10,0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                    </Border>





                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>

    </Setter>


</Style>

<Style TargetType="TextBox" 
BasedOn="{StaticResource textboxPasswordboxStyles}">
</Style>
<Style TargetType="PasswordBox" 
BasedOn="{StaticResource textboxPasswordboxStyles}">
</Style>
```